# Can build target but can't create archive

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, archiving, haneke

I have a target that has a Today Extension. Everything works fine except when I try to create an archive to upload to the store.

The error is the following:

```
No module named "Haneke"
```

This error is from the Today Extension, which obviously works fine on the simulator but gives error when archiving.

I followed the instructions on the Haneke github page, which are the following:

```
1- Drag Haneke.xcodeproj to your project in the Project Navigator.
2- Select your project and then your app target. Open the Build Phases panel.
3- Expand the Target Dependencies group, and add Haneke.framework.
4- Click on the + button at the top left of the panel and select New Copy Files Phase. Set Destination to Frameworks, and add Haneke.framework.
5- import Haneke whenever you want to use Haneke.
```

The first time I install Haneke, I did it only on the target, no the today extension. Then, I did the same with the today extension, but the error still happens. I already tried to delete everything on the DerivedData folder.

Again, everything works fine on simulator, but the problem is when archiving.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work on a device, also?

Comment: Yea seconding what @diatrevelo said? Have you tried on a device?

Comment: Yes, on a real device works...

Comment: @estemendoza I've had that happen to me with a watch extension before and it turned out to be a framework not codesigned properly, but that was a personal framework not a 3rd party, not sure how that affects it

Comment: @bolnad interesting... and how did you solved it?

Comment: @estemendoza i resigned it

Answer (score 0):

Some APIs are unavailable to extensions so check to make sure that this framework your trying to add doesn't reference something that isn't allowed

Here's the rules from Apple's [Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6) on what isn't allowed